# How do i parse the KairosSDK JSON recognise response in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, image-recognition, face-recognition

For those who don't know what the Kairos SDK is, it's basically a facial recognition api.

When you give it an image, it will tell you who if they can match you with someone in the database.

When i give it an image; the api sends me back this response:

```
[images: (
    {
    attributes =         {
        gender =             {
            confidence = "80%";
            type = F;
        };
    };
    candidates =         (
                    {
            "enrollment_timestamp" = 1436883322;
            face3rd = "0.988351106643677";
        },
                    {
            "enrollment_timestamp" = 1436883214;
            hi = "0.94137054681778";
        },
                    {
            "enrollment_timestamp" = 1436883132;
            hi = "0.94137054681778";
        }
    );
    time = "6.43676";
    transaction =         {
        confidence = "0.988351106643677";
        "distance_apart" = "0.046980559825897";
        "gallery_name" = test1;
        height = 482;
        "matching_threshold" = "0.4";
        "next_subject" = hi;
        "next_subject_confidence" = "0.94137054681778";
        "simularity_threshold" = "0.1";
        status = success;
        subject = face3rd;
        topLeftX = 148;
        topLeftY = 92;
        width = 482;
    };
}
)]
```

What i have done is put three images in the database and have called each of them respectively, face3rd, hi, hi (sorry for the two hi's)

I have been trying to parse the names and the number next to it for soo long, i can get around the 6 second response time.

The reason i have not been able to get the names is because, as you can see, i don't know what to tell Swift to look for. The image name changes depending on who i get back.

I don't know if i've explained my situation, bestly, but if you look at the response. The parts that say:

```
face3rd = "0.988351106643677";
hi = "0.94137054681778";
hi = "0.94137054681778";
```

I need the information on both sides of the equal sign.

Thank you for your help and apologise, if reading it was pedantic or you felt like their was a lot of repetion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is poorly formatted JSON that we are returning.  We will fix it in an upcoming version of the API (no release date at this time..sorry).

If all you need is the closest match, you can just access the subject variable directly and ignore the candidates array.

Otherwise, you would need to parse the candidates array manually unfortunately.  I'm not sure how to do that in Swift.

Comment: what do you mean by parse manually? Can you supply it in another language?